# Create self extracting (.exe) zip from the command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-command-prompt, compression

Trying to automate a manual procedure in place currently.  This is on a Windows 2008 server.

Is there a method to create a self extracting (.exe) zip file from a commandline/batch file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not without additional software installed on the machine, such as WinZip or WinRAR or 7-Zip, etc.

If you do have one of these other pieces of software, then you'll need to reference its command line options.

Comment: Is [iexpress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22266511/iexpress-command-line-example-to-create-exe-packages) available in Windows 2008 Server?